# How to find a partner to learn English together?

Tags: discussion

I'm a Chinese. I want to find a friend from abroad to practise English. I think that it will be better to learn a language by communication.

I appreciate it if you know some ways or some platforms.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Are you located in China and limited to things allowed through the Great Firewall, or do you have access to the open Internet?

Comment: Try [hellotalk](hellotalk.com) or [iTalki](italki.com). The second you pay for but you get someone to talk to who knows how to do conversation for language learners.

Comment: You may  want to search on [ell.se] or [languagelearning.se] to get better direction.

Comment: [ell.se] has a Resources for learning English thread that has [a "Exchanging online with a partner" section](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953) the might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: When I was in Mexico on my first sabbatical, I posted a bilingual notice at the local university offering to trade English for Spanish conversation and practice. I made some good friends and learned a lot of Spanish that way. But it's local, so it depends on where you are and who's available. You should only do this with a native speaker; otherwise you're learning the local slang and not much more.